# Multi Signer DocuSign Issue

Tags: .net, email, docusignapi

I am trying to send docusign document to multiple signer .I have added two signer 
and call CreateEnvelope method to send documents .I am using .net framework to implement this .but the problem is mail delivered only first recipients .Can you please help me how can i send document to multiple signer .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're more likely to get help here if you post your code showing what you've tried thus far (rather than just expecting someone to provide the entire solution for you from scratch).

Comment: Hi Kim.This is my code :below section is my code.First added signers and then add it to recipients object.After that create envelope and send it to createenvelope method

Comment: Signer signer1 = new Signer();
            signer1.Email = ds_signer1_email;
            signer1.Name = ds_signer1_name;
            signer1.RecipientId = "1";
            signer1.RoutingOrder = "1";
            signer1.Tabs = tabs1;
            //signer1.Tabs.SignHereTabs.Add(sign_here_tab1);
            //signer1.Tabs.FullNameTabs.Add(full_name_tab1);
            //signer1.Tabs.DateSignedTabs.Add(date_signed_tab1);

Comment: Signer signer2 = new Signer();
            signer2.Email = ds_signer2_email;
            signer2.Name = ds_signer2_name;
            signer2.RecipientId = "2";
            signer2.RoutingOrder = "2";
            signer2.Tabs = tabs2;

Comment: Recipients recipients = new Recipients();
            recipients.Signers = new List<Signer>();
            recipients.Signers.Add(signer1);
            recipients.Signers.Add(signer2);

Comment: EnvelopeDefinition envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
            envelope_definition.EmailSubject = "Please sign the documents";
            envelope_definition.Documents = new List<Document>();
            envelope_definition.Documents.Add(document1);
           
            envelope_definition.Recipients = recipients;
            envelope_definition.EventNotification = event_notification;
            envelope_definition.Status = "sent";

Comment: EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(WebhookLibrary.Configuration);
     
            

            EnvelopeSummary envelope_summary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(WebhookLibrary.AccountId, envelope_definition, null);

Comment: Thank you. For future reference, you should include your code in your original post, rather than adding as (multiple) comments.  You can edit your original post to add code there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've provided, it looks like you're specifying a *serial* routing order:

- first signer is routing order **1**: `signer1.RoutingOrder = "1";`
- second signer is routing order **2**: `signer2.RoutingOrder = "2";`

This is telling DocuSign to send **signer1** their signing invitation email first, and to send **signer2** their signing invitation email only once **signer1** has completed signing.

If you do not care which person signs first (and want them both to receive the email right away when the envelope is sent), set **RoutingOrder** to **1** for both signers.

```
signer1.RoutingOrder = "1";
signer2.RoutingOrder = "1";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .I will try to do it and let you know the update

Comment: Happy to help!  If this resolves your issue, please mark this answer as "Accepted" so that others may benefit from this information in the future. Thanks!